# Increasing performance in connection to Teradata

Tags: python, database-connection, teradata

I need to connect to Teradata using Python. The problem I am facing is the long time to connect to database.

I am trying with `teradata`, `teradatasql` and `pyodbc` packages in Python. The code I am using is something like:

```
import teradata
import teradatasql
import pyodbc
import time

udaExec = teradata.UdaExec (appName="HelloWorld", version="1.0", logConsole=False)

try:
  host, username, password = 'teradata', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxx'
  tic = time.perf_counter()
  session = teradatasql.connect(host=host, user=username, password=password, logmech="LDAP")
  toc = time.perf_counter()
  print(f"TERADATASQL:  {toc - tic:0.4f} seconds")

  tic = time.perf_counter()
  udaExec.connect(method="odbc", dsn="TD")
  toc = time.perf_counter()
  print(f"TERADATA:  {toc - tic:0.4f} seconds")

  tic = time.perf_counter()
  connection = pyodbc.connect('DSN=TD')
  toc = time.perf_counter()
  print(f"PYODBC:  {toc - tic:0.4f} seconds")

except Exception as e:
  print(e)
```

The usual result is something around the following values:

> TERADATASQL:  6.2150 seconds

> TERADATA:  2.8512 seconds

> PYODBC:  2.6051 seconds

The problem is that most part of time I´ll make very simple queries that costs much less than 1 second.

I developed (by myself) a scheme using a pool of 5 pre opened connections. But I think this is very rudimentar, since it is a django serving a REST API service with multiple users. Are there any way to increase the performance to open connections? Any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

to me it looks like you compare LDAP authentification (TERADATASQL) with the default -authentification TD2 (UDAExec & PyODBC). To compare it completely the ODBC.ini would be useful to know the details of DSN being used.

Beside this there is nothing I'm aware you can do to speed up the connection step, except eliminating the step by using some open connections. Although even 2 secs are quite slow to me, whereas I would check the networking / routing to optimize this.

As you mention it's done to include Teradata to REST Calls, did you try to connect directly to Teradata via REST? (Called "Teradata QueryService")